# Change Table Row Class

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So, basically I have a table, built dynamically through `ng-repeat` in which, for each row of the table, if the quantity field is greater than 0 there's a http request that will transfer that quantity from one *Origin Warehouse* to a *Destination Warehouse*.

My current code is:

```
$scope.TransferByOrder = function(){

    for(i = 0; i < $scope.reservesTableByOrder.length; i++){

        if($scope.reservesTableByOrder[i].quant > 0){

            var URL = "/ws/movtransf?func_number="+$scope.func.number+"&art_cod="+$scope.reservesTableByOrderF[i].art_cod+"&origin_ware="+$scope.ware.origin+"&dest_ware="+$scope.ware.dest+"&quant="+$scope.reservesTableByOrder[i].quant+"&ocor="+$scope.reservesTableByOrderF[i].ocor;

        var config = { headers: {
                        'line': i+1,
                        'art_cod': $scope.reservesTableByOrderF[i].art_cod                  }
                };

        $http.get(URL, config).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                //alert("Line: " + config.headers.line + "\nArt_Cod: " + config.headers.art_cod + "\nStatus: Success!");
        }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Line: " + config.headers.line + "\nArt_Cod: " + config.headers.art_cod + "\nStatus: " + data);
        });
        }
    }
    $scope.showOk = true;
    //loadTableByOrder();
};
```

(Code was 'translated' to English, original version is working as intended).

Basically, what I want to do is change the background of a specific table row to green or red either if the request on that row was successfull or not.

The problem is that I can't seem to access the `reservesTableByOrder` array within the `success` or `error`, therefore I can't change the class for that specific row.

Any help would be a life (work) saver :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that helps, but you can add a class through [ng-class directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="red:item.success,green:!item.success"></div>
```

greetings